# Upgrading from PRISM 5 to 6

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-5, prism-6

We have an application which currently uses PRISM 5 which we migrated from PRISM 4 using the upgrade notes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921144(v=pandp.40).aspx

Are there similar upgrade notes from PRISM 5 to 6?

I am interested in the breaking changes so that we plan the upgrade accordingly.

UPDATE: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes---6.0.0

Comment: I managed to find only this: [Prism 6 compatibility with older versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33610897/3060520)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism is now maintained on github https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/ by the community.

There are a wiki section where you can find some release notes with the breaking changes.